# Windows LoadLibrary I can not load the dll from folder

Tags: c++, loadlibrary

Hello I can not load the dll from a selected folder 
using the Windows LoadLibrary 
receives a conditional statement "can not load library" 
Here's the [code](http://s28.postimg.org/5n1dja5bx/image.jpg).

Comment: Please *add* the code to the question rather than linking to a *picture* of the code

Comment: Also, what is the exact error code that you're getting?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` have to say? Do you really want to load from the root of C: ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, find out what the reason for failure is by calling 'GetLastError'.  You will need to translate the code to a string, or look it up online.  Second, it is likely that some dependent DLL loaded by your DLL is not in the current directory or your path or one of the directories enumerated her:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx